# Using SOQL queries in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, soql

I have to use SOQL queries within a Spring Data Repository, Is there a way to do so by using @Query annotation ? If not is there a alternative way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know salesforce doesn't expose the table structures. Rather they expose their objects and you can write queries on them. spring-data-jpa is used on top of an entity framework like hibernate. Unless you have entity objects mapped to actual database tables, spring-data-jpa is not useful.

The best way would be to use a query builder like [jooq](https://www.jooq.org/) and construct SOQL queries easily using query builders.

Comment: So even if the entity objects  are mapped to the actual database tables, spring-data-jpa  cant be used ?

Comment: In that case, you would be connecting to a database and you can use spring-data-jpa the usual way. You won't be dealing with `SOQL` then. `SOQL` is used only for querying on salesforce objects.